# Sampling package - strange behaviour of strata function

Tags: r

In function strata I declare numer of units to be drawn from each stratum and after executing it I get strange result. Numer of units is different from which I declared.

Here is example:

```
library(sampling)
data(swissmunicipalities)
st=strata(swissmunicipalities,stratanames=c("REG"),size=c(30,20,45,15,20,11,44),method="srswor")
```

Result:

```
> table(st$REG)
 1   2   3  4   5    6  7 
20 15 45 30 20 11 44
```

Should be:

```
30,20,45,15,20,11,44
```

I would be very grateful for anwsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the help page of the strata function, you have :

> ```
> size: vector of stratum sample sizes (in the order in which the
>       strata are given in the input data set).
> ```

Let's check this order in which numbers are in the REG variable

```
require(sampling)
data(swissmunicipalities)
swiss <- swissmunicipalities
unique(swiss$REG)
## [1] 4 1 3 2 5 6 7
```

As you can see they are not naturally orderered, so you have two options.

First options, write the size in same order as the original data.

```
size <- c(15, 30, 45, 20, 20, 11, 44)
st <- strata(swiss, stratanames = "REG", size = size, method = "srswor")
table(st$REG)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
## 30 20 45 15 20 11 44
```

Second option, order the data first and keep you size as you first wrote it

```
swiss <- swiss[order(swiss$REG), ]
st <- strata(swiss, stratanames = "REG", size = c(30, 20, 45, 15, 20, 11, 44), 
method = "srswor")
table(st$REG)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
## 30 20 45 15 20 11 44
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this. :)